# how to control speed in this javascript toggle

Tags: javascript, performance, toggle

i want control speed in this function , please help me!

```
<script>
   function toggle(target)
   {   
      var artz = document.getElementsByClassName('showhidemenu');
      var targ = document.getElementById(target);  
      var isVis = targ.style.display=='block';    
      // hide all
      for(var i=0;i<artz.length;i++)
      {
       artz[i].style.display = 'none';
      }   
     // toggle current  
     targ.style.display = isVis?'none':'block';
    return false;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: please give details of your problem.

Comment: By speed you mean... delay? animation?

Comment: this code show my menu very fast , i want change this speed!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a delay, try this:

```
   function toggle(target, milliseconds)
   {
      setTimeout(function() {   
          var artz = document.getElementsByClassName('showhidemenu');
          var targ = document.getElementById(target);  
          var isVis = targ.style.display=='block';    
          // hide all
          for(var i=0;i<artz.length;i++)
          {
              artz[i].style.display = 'none';
          }   
          // toggle current  
          targ.style.display = isVis?'none':'block';
          return false;
       }, milliseconds);
   }
```

You'll lose the return value, though.

Comment: i want show with animation like "hide help" button in this site for comments!

Comment: Set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML, CSS and JS or we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Call your toggle function with an timeout as per your requirement

Use
 window.setTimeout(toggle(),2000);

This will call your toggle function after a delay of 2000 ms.

Comment: tanx, i want show with animation
like "hide help" button in this site for comments!

Comment: `toggle` shouldn't have parentheses in this example. The first parameter to `setTimeout`is either a string to eval or a callable object (function name or inline function)

Comment: @randombumper:yeah it should have been without the parantheses.@amit:could you please share your code so that we could help set up a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

cant show this function with animation ??

```
 function toggle(target, milliseconds)
   {
      setTimeout(function() {   
          var artz = document.getElementsByClassName('showhidemenu');
          var targ = document.getElementById(target);  
          var isVis = targ.style.display=='block';    
          // hide all
          for(var i=0;i<artz.length;i++)
          {
              artz[i].style.display = 'none';
          }   
          // toggle current  
          targ.style.display = isVis?'none':'block';
          return false;
       }, milliseconds);
   }
```

Comment: Any animation would be highly dependent on your actual HTML and CSS.